# Salesforcef DX: How to create a scratch org that opens in Classic by default?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I'm creating browser tests and some of my tests are for Classic Salesforce. I want to avoid running the tests and having an extra step of switching from Lightning to Classic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After org creation you could execute anonymous Apex that sets `UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred = false` on the User object.

You could also open up the scratch org to the URL: **/ltng/switcher?destination=classic**

And then all subsequent requests will open in Classic.

Comment: The approach of opening the URL Charles provided works fine. The approach of using anonymous apex did not work for me, the script updated the User object ok, but after opening the scratch org it got reverted to 'true'.

Comment: Thanks @OscarScholten - maybe this is a change in a new API version?